# How do i get the highest available number in a substring of a list item

Tags: c#, list

I have an algorithm to retrieve the substring 000000 from the string of format AG000123. I am passing these values to a list. As i loop through each of the list items i want to find the highest available number for the substring.In the substring im retrieving the HIGHEST non-zero integer part only eg  if my list has AG000115, AG000123 then i need to retrieve 123. I then want to increment 123 by 1 based on the index of another list e.g if the other list contains 10 items then i increment  as 124, 125 up to 134. Then for each of these generate back to AG000124, AG000125 up AG000134. I need help on how i can retrieve the highest available number for the given substrings in my list items.

This is how im retrieving my list :

```
    private static List<String> GetAgentCodes()
    {

        List<String> items = new List<String>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Helpers.DatabaseConnect))

        {    
            const string Sql =@"SELECT Linked_Sun_Id FROM  WHERE Linked_Sun_Id LIKE '%' + @AG + '%';";          

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(Sql, Conn))
        {       
            ....
            ....
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    string item = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Linked_Sun_Id"));
                    items.Add(item);
                     foreach (string itemm in items)
                    {
                        string substr = itemm.Substring(itemm.Length - 3);

                        List<String> trimmedTems = new List<String>();
                        trimmedTems.Add(substr);

                         foreach (string counter in trimmedTems)
                        {

                        //get highest value in counter
                        //get index of items in related list
                        //if related list has 10 items
                        //value +=10
                        //pass results to another list whilst appending back AG000
                        //List<String> generatedIds = new List<String>();
                          generatedIds.Add(value);



                        }

                    }

                }
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: I believe that the solution you're looking for is called "regular expressions". There are different regular expressions to match different kinds of strings, such as numbers. Here's a good example showing how you can use regular expressions to search for, and return strings within strings that match a rule specified by a regular expression: https://regexone.com/references/csharp

Comment: You need to take a step back and rethink your algorithm. First, separate data access from your logic. Every time you read a value and add it to `items`, you iterate through all elements in `items`. The amount of processing will increase every iteration and balloon as your data set increases. Second, if you take the substring following `"AG"` (i.e. all the digits) and parse that as an `int`, you won't have to worry about how to handle rolling over from `000999` to `001000`, and then from `009999` to `010000`, and so on. That'll make incrementing easier, too, because it's in numeric form.

Comment: When you need to reconstruct the string, use `"AG" + num.ToString("000000")` so you don't have to think about how many zeroes to prepend to the number. Instead, you're telling it how many total digits you want in the output and it'll left-pad with zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regex with int.parse. This code should work

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var strings = GetSamples();
            var highestNumber =  strings.Select(s => int.Parse(Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").Value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)).Max();
            Console.WriteLine(highestNumber);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<String> GetSamples()
        {
            yield return "AG000104";
            yield return "AG000176";
            yield return "AG000296";
            yield return "AG000201";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing displays in the console. It just pops up and dissapears without showing 296

Comment: I am able to reterieve  using T-SQL as follows :SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(Linked_Sun_Id, 4, LEN(Linked_Sun_Id)-3) AS INT)) FROM BrokerMappings WHERE Linked_Sun_Id LIKE 'AG%'